# Angular2 - bringing component into view if it is not fully in view

Tags: angular

Is there any good Angular2 way to bring a component into view?

I tried to use the elementRef's nativeElement function scrollIntoView(), but it behaves strangely on different browsers and it just jumps, instead of transitioning on a position.

I know I could probably achieve this with jQuery, but I don't wont to introduce it into project.